# How to debugg IE11 APPCACHE

Tags: php, internet-explorer, mime-types, html5-appcache

I got an HTML5 page that works with CHROME and SAFARI
but using Internet Explorer 11 it does not work, my cache manifest is valid according to http://manifest-validator.com/ and I'm very frustrated...

here's the paste of the AppCache manifest:

[image: mime type recognized]

```
#version 1.1 12-20-2013
CACHE:

#images
imgs/enc1.png
imgs/logo-izq.png
#internal HTML documents
index.php
#style sheets
css/css.css
css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css
#style sheet images
css/images/animated-overlay.gif
css/images/ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png
css/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png
css/images/ui-bg_glass_55_fbf9ee_1x400.png
css/images/ui-bg_glass_65_ffffff_1x400.png
css/images/ui-bg_glass_75_dadada_1x400.png
css/images/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png
css/images/ui-bg_glass_95_fef1ec_1x400.png
css/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png
css/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png
css/images/ui-icons_2e83ff_256x240.png
css/images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png
css/images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png
css/images/ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png
#javascript files
js/jquery.min.js
js/offline.js
js/jquery-ui.min.js
#FORMULARIOS OFFLINE
1/4-offline.php
1/5-offline.php
1/6-offline.php
2/4-offline.php
2/5-offline.php
2/6-offline.php
3/4-offline.php
3/5-offline.php
3/6-offline.php
NETWORK:
*
FALLBACK:
js/online.js js/offline.js
online.php offline.php
/ offline_plantilla.php
```

and the devel site is this one:

The error on IE11 is the following:
Something like: The resource doesn't exist on server.

[image: Something like: The resource doesn't exist on server.]

Comment: IE 11 does not work with appcache if some file in the manifest (or the index itself) works with PHP SESSION

Answer (score 5):

Add

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
```

To any data php returns.  The default Cache-Control header from php contains "no-store" which will mess up the appCache in both IE 11 and Firefox.

Comment: This is the real solution. It may be impossible to remove `session_start` without loosing all functionality

Answer (score 1):

IE 11 does not work with appcache if some file in the manifest (or the index itself) works with PHP SESSION

You need to remove from every PHP any of this atributtes:

session_start

cache no expire no store

make sure MimeType is correct

Comment: This is 100% correct. Thanks, bacho. I was having problems getting appcache to work in firefox and IE 11 even when it worked correctly in Chrome. I searched *everywhere*. And although lots of people mentioned the "cache no expire no store" point, *NO-ONE* else mentioned PHP's session_start. And yet this was exactly my problem; I removed the session_start and the appcache now works correctly on Firefox and IE 11. So now I am curious why session_start causes the appcache to fail in IE 11. Can someone explain this?

Comment: If the web app requires `session_start`, then this is not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
```

after session_start()