# HTML5 application cache: How to exclude the htm-file from cache where the manifest is defined

Tags: html, caching, manifest, application-cache

We are using **HTML5** application cache in our `single-page-web-application`. The manifest-file is defined in the -tag of the `index.htm-file`:

```
<html xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx manifest="/xxxxxx/xxxxx.appcache">
```

The `index.htm-file` is the only `htm-file` which is loaded from the webserver because the web-application is single-page-web-application build with **angularJS**. All the following responses are in `JSON`.

Now we would like that the `index.htm-file` is not cached in the **HTML5** application cache. But because the manifest-file is defined in the `index.htm-file` this later file is also implicitly cached.

Does anyone know how this could be done that the `index.htm-file` is not cached although the manifest is defined in the `index.htm-file`?

Comment: Please make sure to update this if you have found your answer.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into caching problems with http://dukecon.org. Please check out the discussion here: [how to selectively disable cache for spring boot (manifest.appcache)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26216742/how-to-selectively-disable-cache-for-spring-boot-manifest-appcache/32695747#32695747).

Maybe the second part of our solution will address your issue too: Setting a no-cache header for the `index.html` file? This is performed with a `ServletFilter`: https://github.com/dukecon/dukecon_server/blob/master/impl/src/main/java/org/dukecon/server/impl/CacheManifestFilter.groovy

HTH!